# Writing an XML Schema for pseudo-html

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to write a schema for some XML that is like HTML.
It has < b >< u >< i >< font >< img > tags all inside < p >(aragraph) tags. The problem is they can be in any order:

```
<p> <u><b>test</u><b> </p>
```

or

```
<p> <b><u>test</u></b> </p>.
```

I am trying to create a self referential complex type but I always get "invalid schema" errors. If anyone can guide me to the correct way to do this I would be much appreciated.

Schema:

```
<xs:element name="HTMLDocument">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="p" type="textElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="textElements" mixed="true">
  <xs:group>
    <xs:element name="b" type="textElements"/>
    <xs:element name="i" type="textElements"/>
    <xs:element name="u" type="textElements"/>
    <xs:element name="a" type="textElements"/>
    <xs:element name="font" type="textElements">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="size" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="face" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="img">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:group>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaaah, curse you XML Schema!

Sorry, just need to let that out sometimes. I think this does what you want, but some testing wouldn't be bad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="HTMLDocument">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="p" type="textElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="textElements" mixed="true">
            <xs:group ref="textElementGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:group name="textElementGroup">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="b" type="textElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="i" type="textElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="u" type="textElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="a" type="textElements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="font" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:extension base="textElements">
                            <xs:attribute name="size" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="face" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="img" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:decimal"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

EDIT: oh, looks like you don't need that extra xs:sequence. I'll take it out...

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly. I'm new to xml schema and the "gaaah" resonates with me...

Comment: @shane I'm not new to XML Schema and still it manages to drive me to near insanity every time. I'll never comprehend how something can work so counter-intuitively. Sometimes in the evening when I'm alone at the office, I print out its spec and then immediately run it through a paper shredder. Anyway, I think you get the point.

Comment: @bmargulies Yes, oh yes... I'd love that so much. But the support in Java seems to range from "experimental" to "not updated in 5 years". I'm a bit hesitant to go for it. But I'd so love to use any other schema language...

Comment: In Java 1.6 it's an equal citizen with W3C XML Schema.

Comment: @bmargulies Hmm, interesting. But the XML validation API is by contract only required to support W3C XML Schema, and even if the standard implementation may do so, RNG support for JAXB is still experimental if I'm not mistaken. That's my biggest use-case. Then again, Schemas for JAXB usage don't tend to have the sort of challenge as above. I'm mostly just using it to generate code for my lazy ass.

Comment: JAXB -- if you need that, you are correct that W3C is what you are stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

A good design pattern for this is to use abstract elements and substitution groups. Define the content model of textElements as `<xs:element ref="inline" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`. Define `inline` as an abstract element. Define elements b, i, u etc to be in the substitution group of inline. Define the content model for inline to be textElements.

The advantage of this approach is that you (or your successors) can add new elements to the substitution group at any time with zero impact on existing definitions.